# Scroll to element not working? Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This is for our website and we do not know why when you click 'apply'. It doesn't take you to that part of the page. 
It should be able to scroll to that point on the page and have the title of that section at the top. 
Please could you help us, thank you!

```
<a onclick="scrollTo('#apply')"><li class="li">Apply</li></a>
```

You can see here that I want it to scroll down to the div called #apply when you click this anchor tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  function scrollTo(place) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(place).offset().top }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: Move `scrollTo` outside `$(document).ready(function(){` or better use unobtrusive event handler (bind event using jQuery)

Comment: ...because functions called from `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers have to be globals. It's one of the many reasons not to use them.

Comment: Please find [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k115zdza/)